# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:meta/meta.dart'

Tags: android, flutter, here-api

I`m using the flutter plugin of here to execute de **hello_map_app example**.
I follow the instructions of  https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.1.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html

to I did **`flutter pub get`**, restarted Android studio but I have errors in the pluggin.

[Errors reported in Android Studio Dart Analisis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By3Mo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please directly import the hello_map example from this link - https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/explore/flutter

Unzip the HERE SDK for Flutter plugin to the plugins folder that can be found inside the example app project. Rename the folder to 'here_sdk': hello_map/plugins/here_sdk
Set your HERE SDK credentials to
hello_map/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
hello_map/ios/Runner/Info.plist

**Please Note Following:**
Your IDE should use -
Flutter 2.2.2
Dart version 2.13.3
Newer versions may also work, but are not guaranteed to work. The Flutter version 2.0.6 and Dart 2.12.0 are also supported. It is recommended to use the Dart version that is bundled with Flutter.